# how to delete even elements from a 3D array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3D array with a shape `(255,255,158)` these are 158 images of 255x255 resolution.

How can I delete even a number of images, so the shape should be like `(255,255,79)`?

Comment: isn't important to decide which ones you want to delete OR are you saying delete the "even" images, i.e. index 0, index 2, index 4, etc ....

Comment: It's not important which images, just delete even images.

Comment: Please define `even image`

Comment: from indexes, 0, 2, 4. . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use numpy's [`delete`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html?highlight=delete#numpy.delete) function, for example if you want to delete the first, 50-th and 78-th image of your `array` you can simply do :

```
index = np.array([0, 49, 77])
output = np.delete(array, index, axis=-1)
```

If you want every even index to be deleted, you can do :

```
index = np.arange(0, array.shape[2], 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can always just use the python colon function

http://www.hpc-carpentry.org/hpc-python/03-lists/index.html

```
arr = arr[:,:,:int(arr.shape[2]/2)]
```